# Can't extract multiple .css files from a single .js entry (imported multiple .scss files)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

*I raised this issue at [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) but it seems this plugin doesn't support this feature at the moment (I'm not sure).*

How can I extract `main.scss` and `home.scss` into `main.css` and `home.css` in the following example?

**Result:** There was no error, but only `home.css` was created.

**home.js**

```
import '../scss/main.scss';
import '../scss/home.scss';
```

**main.scss**

```
.test1 { color: #f00; }
```

**home.scss**

```
.test2 { color: #00f; }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let webpack = require('webpack');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
    }]
  },
  entry: {
    'home': './scripts/home.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/static/scripts',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css')
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack creates a bundle per entry, so if you have only the `home` entry and expect `[name].css`, you get only `home.css`. This is what you can do instead:

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry: {
  'home': './scripts/home.js',
  'main': './scripts/main.js'
}
```

and import relevant scss files in both `home.js` and `main.js`.

A cleaner solution would be to separate entries for scss and js assets and use array entries:

```
entry: {
  'home': ['./scripts/home.js', './scss/home.scss'],
  'main': ['./scripts/main.js', './scss/main.scss']
}
```

Comment: Surely it works this way, actually I did it before posting this question. Just concerning about the questioned case.

Comment: @TienDo what is exactly your case? A bundle per scss `import` in a javascript file? It would be the opposite of how webpack works.

Comment: Yes, I wanted it, but you're right that it's not Webpack way :)